# Unity: Merge TMPPro sprite assets

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have currently created 4 sprite assets using TextMeshPro.

[image: Here is a capture of my sprite repository]

However, I would like to have an atlas containing the 4 of them. Is there any way to merge them ?
I don't have a texture containing these 4 sprites, I just have them in 4 separate pngs files.

Comment: So you want to create one texture file containing these 4 sprites? Or do you mean a [`SpriteAtlas`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteAtlas.html)?

Comment: I want to have a single atlas with these 4 sprites, can I do it without creating a single texture these sprites ?

Answer (score 2):

Following [this video](https://youtu.be/hlatyQC-xIg?t=615), you can actually reference the sprite asset directly in the sprite tag.

`<sprite="ASSET NAME" index=0>`

Just replace ASSET NAME with the actual name of your sprite asset. As another example,

`<sprite="resource_a" index=0>`

Just note that the asset name is case-sensitive.

Side note: I would look into putting the icons into the same sprite atlas to help reduce the number of draw calls. The more you have, the slower your game will run per frame.